# Gulp + SASS + BrowserSync don’t work on newly created partials

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I’m using a pretty simple setup for Gulp with SASS and BrowserSync.

```
//require plugins here

// Paths

var styleSRC = './assets/css/style.scss'; // Path to main .scss file.
var styleDestination = './  '; 
var styleWatchFiles = './assets/css/**/*.scss'; 


// BrowserSync
gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: projectURL,
        open: false,
        injectChanges: true  
    });
});


//Task

gulp.task('styles', function () {
    gulp.src(styleSRC)
        .pipe(sass({
            errLogToConsole: true,
        }))
        .on('error', console.error.bind(console)).pipe(autoprefixer(AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(styleDestination))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});

// Watch
gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'browser-sync'], function () {
    gulp.watch(styleWatchFiles, ['styles']); 
});
```

The issue is though this setup doesn’t recognize when new partial file is created. So if I create a partial and then add it to `style.scss` nothing is happening, Sass is not compiled -> so you have manually call the task from the console.

Is it possible to automatically compile Sass when new partial is added?

Comment: can you remove './' from gulp.src and in your watch and try again ?

Comment: Where is your watch task for watching changes to admin-style.scss?  What you describe will not work without a watch task.

Comment: @Dirk seems to work, thanks! Would you like to post it as answer? Any insight why it doesn’t work with `./`?

Comment: it has something to do with how windows handles the path if i remember correctly.

Comment: @Dirk Mac also has this problem, so maybe it’s a cross-platform issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you remove './' from the source path it will work the way you would expect it

as far as i know this is a windows only problem
here is a github issue that describes the problem : https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1422

should be fixed in gulp 4.x , but thats still in alpha